# Why does Query produce this error: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in storagelog.php on line 24

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Working on a storage log application with php/mysql, and I'm having a problem with the SQL query that's kind of supposed to tie the whole thing together.

Basically, the program allows the user to enter in a project with a variety of fields (id#, name of project, customer name, unit of measurement, etc etc). Once a project is created, the storage log page (the one whose code is listed below) displays a separate HTML table for each of those projects. At the bottom of each of those tables is a form, allowing the user to submit a storage in/out transaction. On submit, the transaction is added to a database and then the program redirects to the storage log page.

Now, what I want to do is design the log page so that each transaction is displayed in the table that it corresponds to. So if I have a project with the ID number "15," I want the HTML table to Project 15 to show each transaction for that project in its own row in that table. If the move ID is "14," however, I want the transaction to display ONLY in the table for project #14.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
 $script = '<script> 
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
        }); </script>' ; 
        $title = "View/Edit Storage - " ;
        include('inc/header.php');   
        $projects = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT projectname, moveid, customername, PPU, UoM FROM newproject");
        $transactions = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM newtransaction as t where $tranresults[moveid] == t.moveid"); 

while ($results = mysqli_fetch_array($projects, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<table align='center'>";
        echo "<th colspan='7'>";
            echo $results[moveid] . " -- " . $results[projectname] . " c/o " . $results[customername] . " -- " . "$" . $results[PPU] . "/" . $results[UoM];
        echo "</th>";
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>Move ID</td>";
            echo "<td>In/Out</td>";
            echo "<td>Number of Units</td>";
            echo "<td>Date</td>";
            echo "<td>RR/DT#</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

while ($tranresults = mysqli_fetch_array($transactions, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$tranresults[moveid]</td>";
        echo "<td>$tranresults[IORO]</td>";
        echo "<td>$tranresults[units]</td>";
        echo "<td>$tranresults[transdate]</td>";
        echo "<td>$tranresults[refno]</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}?>
                    <tr>
                    <form action="transadded.php" name='addnewtransaction' method="POST">
                        <td><input type="text" name="moveID" size="20" value="<?php echo $results[moveid]; ?>" readonly> </td>
                        <td><select id="inoutselect" name="inorout">
                                <option value="Select">Select</option>
                                <option value="Storage In">Storage In</option>
                                <option value="Storage Out">Storage Out</option>
                            </select> </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="numberofunits" size="20"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="dateoftransaction" size="20" class="datepicker"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="rrdt" size="20"> </td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Add" id="logsubmit"></td>
                    </form>
                    </table>
                    <br /><br />
    <?php   };?>
```

Disclaimer: I'm aware that the code is currently vulnerable to SQL injection, and I'll be fixing that once the basic functionality is worked out.

Comment: Don't think doing two mysqli_query(...) calls like that is legit. Perform one query, process your results. then do the second query.

Comment: I see this type of question all the time, you should read [common database debugging for PHP and MySQL](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/04/common-debugging-php-mysql/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in your question is because `$transactions` is returning `FALSE` instead of any results. This is because of syntax errors in the SQL you're building. First, you can't just dump an array access into a string - you have to either break out of the string or use curly braces to indicate that you want that variable to be interpolated. Secondly, you should put quotes around the names of keys in your associative array - PHP will figure out what you want but still generate an E_WARNING in the logs. Thirdly, you're using a double equals sign with is invalid SQL.

Here's your original line:

```php
$transactions = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM newtransaction as t where $tranresults[moveid] == t.moveid");
```

and it should be:

```php
$transactions = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM newtransaction as t where {$tranresults['moveid']} = t.moveid");
```

***_* EDIT *_***

From the comments we've discovered that line 9 references a variable that isn't even set until line 24, and is the wrong variable to be looking inside of anyway. Here's another crack at the code, with the 2nd SQL query moved & some of the array accesses cleaned up.

```php
$projects = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT projectname, moveid, customername, PPU, UoM FROM newproject");

while ($results = mysqli_fetch_array($projects, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<table align='center'>";
    echo "<th colspan='7'>";
    echo $results['moveid'] . " -- " . $results['projectname'] . " c/o " . $results['customername'] . " -- " . "$" . $results['PPU'] . "/" . $results['UoM'];
    echo "</th>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Move ID</td>";
    echo "<td>In/Out</td>";
    echo "<td>Number of Units</td>";
    echo "<td>Date</td>";
    echo "<td>RR/DT#</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $transactions = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM newtransaction as t where {$results['moveid']} = t.moveid"); 
    while ($tranresults = mysqli_fetch_array($transactions, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>{$tranresults['moveid']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$tranresults['IORO']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$tranresults['units']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$tranresults['transdate']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$tranresults['refno']}</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, these changes as well as the one you added to the comment below have made no difference.

Comment: Where is the array `$tranresults` coming from? Is it set somewhere earlier in your script that you just haven't pasted into the question for us? There is some reason that this SQL statement is erroring out and returning `FALSE` instead of the rows you want.

Comment: $tranresults is set for the first time in the code provided as part of the while loop. I can't figure out for the life of me why it's returning false.

Comment: That's the problem. In line 9, you are using `$tranresults[]` to build your SQL query, but `$tranresults` doesn't even exist until you try and set it in line 24.

Comment: Now that I think about it, it does seem kind of recursive. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Yes, I will edit my answer to try and fix it, but first a question. Does each project have more than one transaction?

Comment: Yes, the goal is to be able to track the individual transactions for each project to monitor storage totals on a weekly and then monthly basis. The storage amount will be totaled later in the table header.

Comment: This did the trick. I cannot thank you enough. I'm going to read through the code here to figure out the logic, because my knowledge of SQL seems to still have some gaping holes. Thank you so, so much.

Answer (score 0):

Change first this errors: (examples)

```
...$tranresults[moveid] == t.moveid...
```

to

```
...".$tranresults['moveid']." = t.moveid... // equal sign / single quotes
```

Then put `''` in **all** your key names (in your case):

Example:

```
...$results[moveid]...
```

to

```
...$results['moveid']... // with single quotes
```

and when you put key name or variables into a string then have you quote this:

Example:

```
echo "<td>$tranresults[moveid]</td>";
```

to

```
echo "<td>".$tranresults['moveid']."</td>";
```

Comment: I have made these changes, but with no difference in result :(

Though I was a bit confused about which "$results[moveid]" you wanted me to change. It crops up several times in the code. CAn you clarify? Thank you:)

Comment: You should change all of them to have quotes around the key names. PHP will give you an `E_NOTICE: Use of undefined constant moveid - assumed 'moveid'` for every time you access an array without quoting the key name.

Comment: @JayB127 I was not clear enough... all `$variable['']` have to set with single quote..in your case.. EXAMPLE: `SELECT * FROM newtransaction as t where ".$tranresults['moveid']." = t.moveid`